# SEO, content duplication and pagination

Tags: pagination, seo

I have a layout similar to [this](http://www.debate.org/debates/There-is-no-right-or-wrong/1/), only it's not debates, so I'll use this as an example for the question.

As you can see, they have 3 different tabs, for rounds, comments and votes but these are all in one page, whereas in my case, I have different pages for comments and votes like this

```
example.com/post/1      <- main post's url
example.com/post/1/comments
example.com/post/1/votes
```

and both comments and votes are paginated, so there can be urls like this:

```
example.com/post/1/comments/page/3
```

So I wonder how I should manage this kind of situation from the SEO perspective, won't the fixed part of the debate above the tabs considered a duplication? And what happens if I add a canonical link to let's say, comments page, leading to the main post's url, will the comments be indexed or only the main post's page will?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to Webmaster Pro.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for SEO advice. It might be on-topic on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> won't the fixed part of the debate above the tabs considered a duplication?

No, if it is repeated on every page, it will be considered as boiler plate content and be ignored for ranking, because it is not specific to the page itself.

> And what happens if I add a canonical link to let's say, comments page, leading to the main post's url, will the comments be indexed or only the main post's page will?

If Google trusts and agrees with your canonical link, then only the main post will be used for indexing.